# Underscore have some function to extract nested array of objects to new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "listForExtract": [{
        "value1": "1A",
        "value2": "2A"
    }, {
        "value1": "1B",
        "value2": "2B"
    }, ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "listForExtract": [{
        "value1": "1C",
        "value2": "2C"
    }, {
        "value1": "1D",
        "value2": "2D"
    }, ]
}]
```

I want to extract the objects inside `listForExtract` to a new array like using some function of underscore passing the ID:

something like: `_.extractNestedArrayFrom(myArray, 'listForExtract', {'id':2})`

```
[{
    "value1": "1A",
    "value2": "2A"
}, {
    "value1": "1B",
    "value2": "2B"
}]
```

Comment: Lucas.. you can accept any answer below that you find useful..

Comment: I added a comment for finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**where**](http://underscorejs.org/#where), [**pluck**](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) and [**flatten**](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten):

```
var result = _.chain(data)
    .where({id:2})
    .pluck('listForExtract')
    .flatten()
    .value()
```

Where finds all the items in the array that have an `id` of 2 and pluck extracts the `listForExtract`. Flatten is then used to flatten the result into one array

Comment: Is there a way to return the array rather than array inside another array?

Comment: My bad. Added a `flatten` in there to flatten the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and [where](http://underscorejs.org/#where)  methods

```js
var myArray = [{
    "id": 1,
    "listForExtract": [{
        "value1": "1A",
        "value2": "2A"
    }, {
        "value1": "1B",
        "value2": "2B"
    }, ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "listForExtract": [{
        "value1": "1C",
        "value2": "2C"
    }, {
        "value1": "1D",
        "value2": "2D"
    }, ]
}];
var result = _.map(_.where(myArray, {
  'id': 2
}), function(elem) {
  return elem.listForExtract
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Comment: is there a way to return the array rather than array inside another array?

Comment: yes try this _.findWhere(myArray, {'id': 2}).listForExtract

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need `underscore` for that.

Following code should work for you.

```
myArray.filter(function(){
  return o.id==2
}).map(function(o){
  return o.listForExtract
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to return the array rather than array inside another array?

Comment: @Lucas.. no matter what u try from underscore.. it will end up with a filter and a map.. so better use that..